# Multiple Elements.xml in feature.xml in sharepoint 2007

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2007

I was just discussing with my team member of doing multiple things with one share point feature.
Discussion ended with an challenge and i need your little help in here.

I have one questions:

1. Can we do multiple things in feature, like for e.g. I want to create a list and at the same time also want to add new ECB Menu item link for the same list created.

so ca one feature have multiple elements.xml in feature.xml is big question in my head tight now. actually i followed these link and it confuses me,
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/40076dc2-8be6-4019-bf1e-54067880e8a8/

Not sure if sharepoint 2007 does allows these???

Thanks,
Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one feature can have multiple element manifests.

From [ElementManifest Element (Feature)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453427%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> **Occurrences**
>
> Minimum: 0
>
> Maximum: Unbounded

Additionally, the example from [Feature.xml Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475601%28v=office.12%29.aspx) shows multiple element manifests in a single feature:

```
<Feature 
  Id="11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111" 
  Title="Location Services"
  Description="This Feature contains lists and parts that let you link location data to your customer lists."
  Scope="Web">
  <ActivationDependencies>
    <ActivationDependency
      FeatureId="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" />
  </ActivationDependencies>
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest 
      Location="Location\LocationPart.xml"/>
    <ElementManifest 
      Location="CustomerLocation\CustomerLocationList.xml"/>
    <ElementFile 
      Location="test.aspx"/>
  </ElementManifests>
  <Properties>
    <Property
      Key="Color"
      Value="Blue"/>
    <Property
      Key="Shape"
      Value="Triangle"/>
  </Properties> 
</Feature>
```

One point to note, you specifically asked if a single feature can contain multiple files named Elements.xml. The answer to that is also yes, provided that each Elements.xml file is in a unique directory. Since the features rely on the file system, you obviously cannot have two different files both named Elements.xml in the same directory.